# Error calling Android Native Modules with React Native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-studio

I'm implementing an app that will be on a vending machine, for that I'm using a "PagSeguro" card machine and using the [PlugPag](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v1.0/reference/plugpag-android-minizinha-providers) library... As there is no library for React Native, (only in Java), I'm using it in Native Modules process.

Follow the code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NativeModules, Button} from 'react-native';
const App= () => {

  payment = () => {
    NativeModules.PlugPag.doCreditPayment()  
  };

     
  return (
    <Button
        title="test"
        onPress={payment()}
      />
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Java Code:

```
package com.myapp;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

@ReactMethod
public void doCreditPayment() {
        try {
        // WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();

        PlugPagPaymentData paymentData = new PlugPagPaymentData(PlugPag.TYPE_CREDITO, 110,
        PlugPag.INSTALLMENT_TYPE_A_VISTA, 1, "APPDEMO");

        PlugPagAppIdentification appIdentification = new PlugPagAppIdentification("MeuApp", "1.0.7");

        PlugPag plugpag = new PlugPag(reactContext, appIdentification);

        PlugPagInitializationResult result = plugpag
        .initializeAndActivatePinpad(new PlugPagActivationData("403938"));

        if (result.getResult() == PlugPag.RET_OK) {

        plugpag.setEventListener(plugPagEventData -> {
        // you can add another listener here
        }


        PlugPagTransactionResult transResult = plugpag.doPayment(paymentData);

        if (transResult.getResult() == PlugPag.RET_OK) {
        //response.invoke(transResult.getTransactionCode());
        emitDeviceEvent("SuccessPayment", transResult.getTransactionCode());

        });
        } else {
        //error.invoke(transResult.getMessage());
        emitDeviceEvent("ErrorPayment", transResult.getMessage());

        });
        }

        // Log.i("GET", "GET " + transResult);

        } else {
        error.invoke(RETURN_ERROR);
        }


        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
        error.invoke(E_LAYOUT_ERROR);
        }

        }

private void emitDeviceEvent(String eventName, String message) {
        Log.i("GET", "GET " + message);
        // A method for emitting from the native side to JS
        // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript
        reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName,
        message);
        }
```

I'm testing with the library with a value already defined, but it's showing the following errors in the compilation:

```
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Error: Command failed:
> gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:11:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected public void
> doCreditPayment() {
>        ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:18:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         PlugPagAppIdentification appIdentification = new PlugPagAppIdentification("MeuApp", "1.0.7");
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:20:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         PlugPag plugpag = new PlugPag(reactContext, appIdentification);
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:22:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         PlugPagInitializationResult result = plugpag
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:25:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         if (result.getResult() == PlugPag.RET_OK) {
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:34:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         if (transResult.getResult() == PlugPag.RET_OK) {
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:38:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         });
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:39:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         } else {
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:43:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         });
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:44:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         }
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:50:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         }
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:55:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         }
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:63:
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
>         reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName,
>         ^ C:\Users\leand\react\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\plugPag.java:63:
> error: <identifier> expected
>         reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName,
>                                                                                      ^ 14 errors
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In java, all functions need to be inside a Class.

In this particular case, it needs to be a class extended from ReactContextBaseJavaModule.. i.e:

```
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    @ReactMethod
    public void doCreditPayment() {
        // your code... 
    }
}
```

Although I believe you also need a @Override public string getName() function when creating a Native java class to use in ReactNative. Full code should be:

```
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    
    @Override
    public String getName(){
       return "MyModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void doCreditPayment() {
        // your code... 
    }
}
```